# Rebuild+Restart from IntelliJ does not filter properties from resources correctly in maven project

Tags: intellij-idea, java-8, maven-3

When I rebuild and restart my software using IntelliJ after an initial maven build, it fails to replace placeholders in property files by their value.

The software is a multi-module project which builds to multiple web applications.
Those web applications are deployed together into a tomcat.

When I build with maven, it works, and the properties are properly filtered. I can start the software using IntelliJ's run configuration and use it or debug it. But when I stop it and later restart the software by triggering IntelliJ’s internal build as part of its tomcat run configuration, the software launches but the property files are not filtered correctly. I get bean initialization errors where the causing exception is something like a `NumberFormatException` because Java could not interpret `"${timeout}"` as a number.

The properties are filtered by the copy-resources maven mojo in the process-resources phase.

I think this has worked before in the not so recent past, so I think there is nothing fundamentally wrong. It still seems to work in most cases, but not all. The software consists of about 15 different webservices deployed together, and only in about five of them this issue occurs.

So far, I've looked for the usage of the copy-resources mojo throughout the pom files. It's invoked in >50 different places, but always in the same way with different settings. So, I figure this is basically working.

**What else could this be? What could trigger this behavior?**

The project is a big heterogenous java maven project with a pretty default tech stack. If you know an IntelliJ feature, a maven plugin or something with the projects structure that could be at fault, feel free to comment.

My IntelliJ version is 2021.1 Ultimate, maven version is the bundled 3.6.3.

Comment: Does it help to invoke this action: https://monosnap.com/file/fC09B7zEtgqIQrk62UdgjJBTHBGsM4 Check also which phase you have set for the Settings (Preferences on macOS) | Build, Execution, Deployment | Build Tools | Maven | Importing | **Phase to be used for folders update** option. Make sure to try with **process-resources** there. Check also the version from https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/nextversion/

Comment: If the problem remains, please file an issue at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA And it would be great if you provided a sample project to reproduce (can be attached privately to YouTrack or uploaded to https://uploads.jetbrains.com/).

Comment: I will consider filing an issue at youtrack when I get no help here. I tried "Generate Sources and Update Folders..." and it took ages. After it finished, I started the software but the compile step had a "circular dependency" issue between 3 exploded artifacts. I think IntelliJ is wrong here, there is no hint as to why those artifacts should have a circular dependency. I will keep looking into it, but even by "View Usages" on the artifacts in project structure, IntelliJ could not tell me where they are used according to its error message.

Comment: The circular dependency was another issue and could be solved. But the original issue still persists, "Generate Sources and Update Folders..." did not help.

Comment: It seems I fixed it. Last monday, I threw my local repo away and cloned it again. Since then, I have not had this issue again. I don't know why, but I suppose something in the .idea-folders was scrambled and re-cloning it (and re-generating by intelliJ) fixed it somehow. I guess that this scrambling was triggered by some module refactorings and movements during the last few weeks. I know of another project with the same issue, where this theory could also apply.